# Find the length of one side of a triangle given two other sides and the length of the angle bisector

Tags: geometry, triangles

For an arbitrary triangle $ABC$.

If given the length of side $AB=15$ and $AC=12$ and the length of the angle bisector that connects angle $A$ to side $BC = 10$. What is the length of $BC$.

I considered using the angle bisector theorem or the length of the angle bisector formula but both times that I've reversed my findings to double-check my work my results have been off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your ideas, using angle bisector theorem:

$BC$ is split in the ratio $4k$ to $5k$.

From the length of the angle bisector formula:

$$180-20k^2=10^2 \implies k=2$$
$$BC=18$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to solve this using Trigonometry. Let ΔABC have sides AB=c BC=a and CA=b then,

$CosA=2Cos^2(A/2)-1$

By cosine rule $CosA=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$

And the length of angle bisector of Angle A is given by,
$AD=\frac{2bcCos(A/2)}{b+c}$

Substituting AD=10 AB=15 AC=12 we get Cos(A/2)=3/4
And then CosA=1/8
And finally use cosine rule to get BC=18

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $AB=c=15$, $AC=b=12$ and $AD=d=10$. Using the length of the angle bisector formula:
$$d^2=b\cdot c\cdot \left[1-\frac{a^2}{(b+c)^2}\right]$$
$$10^2=12\cdot15\cdot\left[1-\frac{a^2}{(12+15)^2}\right]$$
$$100=180\cdot\left[1-\frac{a^2}{729}\right]$$
$$100=180-\frac{180a^2}{729}$$
$$-80=-\frac{180a^2}{729}$$
$$-58320=-180a^2$$
$$324=a^2$$
$$BC=a=18$$

---

Using another length of the angle bisector formula: 
$$d^2=b\cdot c-a_1\cdot a_2$$
$$\frac{b}{c}=\frac{12}{15}=\frac{4}{5}$$
Because of the angle bisector theorem:
$$\frac{a_1}{a_2}=\frac{b}{c}=\frac{4k}{5k}$$
$$10^2=12\cdot 15-4k\cdot 5k$$
$$100=180-20k^2$$
$$-80=-20k^2$$
$$4=k^2$$
$$k=2$$
$$a_1=4k=8$$
$$a_2=5k=10$$
$$a=a_1+a_2=18$$